# Using PassportJS How do I logout a user

Tags: reactjs, passport.js

Please help me understand/solve this. I have a express server running that also uses Passportjs. On the server side of the application, within node modules I see http-request.js which has the following :

```
/**
 * Terminate an existing login session.
 *
 * @api public
 */
req.logout =
req.logOut = function() {
  console.log("REQUEST LOGOUT");
  var property = 'user';
  if (this._passport && this._passport.instance) {
    property = this._passport.instance._userProperty || 'user';
  }
  
  this[property] = null;
  if (this._passport) {
    this._passport.instance._sm.logOut(this);
  }
};
```

If my client side of the application were to call the req.logout() method upon a button click , then how would I do that ? I am lost. Please help me understand this.

This is what I have for as my logout component on the client side.

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {UserContext, HeaderContext} from '../../../context';
import mslogin from '../account-status/mslogin.png';

export function MSLogin(){

    passport = require('passport');

    return(
        <div className='login'>
            <div className='logout-container'>
                <div className='logout-box'>
                    <div className='logout-text'>{'Sign out'}</div>
                    <a className='sign-in-link' href='/api/auth/login'
                             onClick = **HOW DO I CALL req.logout()**>
                        <img src={mslogin} className="ms-img" alt="Microsoft" />
                        {'Sign out'} 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className='spacer' />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To terminate the user session on server side, you can use this function. You have to remove the endpoints using the session ID. If you are using local strategy to generate and store the session this code will terminate that session and user has to login again with new endpoints to authenticate.

```
try {
            let sid = req.sessionID;
            pushNotification.removeEndPointUsingSessionId(sid);

            req.session.destroy(function (err) {
                req.logout();
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            winston.error(err);
        }
```

You can see further about passport strategies [here][1].
[1]: http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/

Comment: Thank you for your response @Muhammad. I am a bit new to JavaScript. How do I access req (for request) on the client side , since it is declared on the server side ?